# How to Invert (Negative) Android Vector Image (Path)

Tags: android, image, vector, togglebutton

Need area bound by Vector to be transparent and background (Remaining area) to be filled. Required to make it easy to dynamically fill color of vector (Toggle Button Drawable) when the same is bound by a Selector

I Have Vector Path for Below generated from Studio: (Amber space is Transparent)

[image]

I want This: (Amber space is Transparent)

[image]

Comment: what do you want to achieve actually? what Path? what Vector?

Comment: @pskink I have updated the question with images - I have to dynamically change color of Toggle button/Selector image - If I have above image it would be sufficient to change the background color and achieve - I have tried backgroundTint But it doesn't support in older version of android

Comment: no, inverted image is something like [this](http://pasteboard.co/4uZ7WCKGG.png)

Comment: @pskink yes that is what I tried to depict - How to achieve it ?

Comment: see `PorterDuffXfermode` with `PorterDuff.Mode.XOR`

Comment: @pskink Do you want to post this answer - It worked for me - I can accept it as correct answer.

Comment: feel free to write an auto answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @pskink - Per his suggestion I used

```
myImageView.setColorFilter(Color.WHITE, PorterDuff.Mode.XOR);
myStateListDrawable.addState(new int[] { android.R.attr.state_checked },  myImageView);
```

To achieve my needs.

Scroll down the below link - there are easy to understand examples with other options for ColorFilter

https://android--examples.blogspot.in/2015/11/android-color-filter-and-different.html